# Nginx domain work without be into sites-enabled

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-12.04

I have a strange bug in my Nginx configuration.

If I stop nginx, every domains stop working, which is normal.

If I remove or comment **include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;** (in nginx.conf) every domains stop working, which is normal.

If I rename the **sites-enabled** folder, nginx wont restart and domain stop working, which is normal.

If I remove the **sites-enabled** folder, nginx wont restart and domain stop working, which is normal.

**But** if I remove a domaine from the **sites-enabled** folder, restart/reload nginx, the domain still working.

How is that possible ? Is there any "config cache" somewhere ?

ps: I already reboot the server manytime, updated Nginx and I have the exact same configuration in another one server where this problem do not appear.

Answer (score -1):

Have you deleted default config which is located in sites-enabled directory? By the way this is not that much critical  issue.

Comment: as per your words it appears that you were little bit worried due to this.That's why I used critical.